# Setting up Datasource in templates

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-query, datasource

I have a Droplink field and I am trying to set the data source in the templates. 
What I want to do is set the data source by id instead of path and also add a filter by templates

For example 
`query:/sitecore/content/sites/home/content/products/*[@@templateid='{4B8840D7-C56C-440F-B97E-973B6860B206}']` 

 This Works. 
But, I don't want to give the path of "**products**" but it's item id because the path can change later.

So i tried

```
datasource={B343ACC6-591C-4E67-8538-D73D87FEE998}
```

and this works. but not sure how to add template filter.

i tried

`datasource={B343ACC6-591C-4E67-8538-D73D87FEE998}/*[@@templateid = '{4B8840D7-C56C-440F-B97E-973B6860B206}']` 

 and other different combinations. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The DropLink does not support a "Parameterized Datasource" where you could use parameters like *Datasource* and *IncludeTemplatesForDisplay*.
But with using the query syntax, it should be possible.

You could try it like this:

```
query://*[@@id = '{B343ACC6-591C-4E67-8538-D73D87FEE998}']/*[@@templateid='{4B8840D7-C56C-440F-B97E-973B6860B206}']
```

as `query://*[@@id = '{...}']` searches through the entire content tree and returns an Item with the mentioned ID.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the Template Filter on the Datasource almost in the same way you are doing 
But I would put the ID, on the Standard values(not on the data source on the template) or on the item itself, I believe this would solve your issue

To learn more about how to Restrict the item by template I would recommend the following link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952880/sitecore-restrict-item-by-data-template-type-on-a-field